# Type 'void[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

This code block is OK:

```
        let attributes = <>
        {
            props.filter.attributes?.map((data) => {
                return
                <div className="form-check">
                    <input className="form-check-input" type="radio" id={data.id.toString()} name={props.filter.name} value={data.name} onChange={props.changeHandler} />
                    <label className="form-check-label">{data.name}</label>
                </div>
            })
        }
    </>
```

But this code has the error `Type 'void[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.` The only change is to wrap the `map` function in a div:

```
    let attributes = <>
        <div className="row row-cols-5">
            {
                props.filter.attributes?.map((data) => {
                    return
                    <div className="form-check">
                        <input className="form-check-input" type="radio" id={data.id.toString()} name={props.filter.name} value={data.name} onChange={props.changeHandler} />
                        <label className="form-check-label">{data.name}</label>
                    </div>
                })
            }
           </div>
        </>
```

What do I need to do to the second example to eliminate the error?

Comment: Isn't the compiler treating the *return* as a complete statement and ignores the div below? Have you tried to put both in the same line of code?

Comment: Try by wrapping the form-check div between round () brackets and then return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your return should looks as follows

```
return (
  <div className="form-check">
    <input className="form-check-input" type="radio" id={data.id.toString()} name={props.filter.name} value={data.name} onChange={props.changeHandler} />
    <label className="form-check-label">{data.name}</label>
  </div>
);
```

So the HTML should be wrapped into brackets. Otherwise, you actually have it as unreachable code and your function looks like simple

```
return;
// Some unreachable html here
```